# Random step generator

Tags: php, random, echo

Need help with random generator and don't know what to call the second question.. Please read...

1)I found this php image generator on the Internet which works quite well !

```
<?php
$my_img = imagecreate( rand(150, 400), 80 );
$background = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255), rand(0, 255) );
$text_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 0, 0, 0 );
$line_colour = imagecolorallocate( $my_img, 128, 255, 0 );
imagestring( $my_img, 4, 30, 25, "thesitewizard.com", $text_colour );
imagesetthickness ( $my_img, 5 );
imageline( $my_img, 30, 45, 165, 45, $line_colour );
header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $my_img );
imagecolordeallocate( $line_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $text_color );
imagecolordeallocate( $background );
imagedestroy( $my_img );
?>
```

I made it randomly generate size and colors but i need the sizes to be more precise...it must randomly generate images width between 150 to 400 stepping 50 pixels at a time

ie... 150 200 250 300 350 400 wide

2) then?
how would i then take that random image and make it show ?

```
<img src="<?php echo $output['my_img']; ?>">
```

Thank you.... Any help Appreciated !

Comment: Basic mathematics: `rand(3,8)*50;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can put your preferred sizes in array or use what Mark Baker suggested.

```
$sizes = array(150,200,250,300,350,400);
$size = $sizes[array_rand($sizes)];
```

For displaying the image you need to call the image generation script from your image tag

```
   <img src='/path/to/image.php' />
```

Comment: thank you very much.. got it working... out of interest ?  how would i randomize 5 names ? because an array as i understand can only be number ?

Comment: arrays can have names too, (strings) like $names = array('sam', 'jon', 'paul');

Comment: can i ask another question? 

im successfully get the image generator to randomise on it own but pulling it into this jquery collage script (http://about.za.org/stackoverflow/examples/example.html) it keep pulling the same image. in other words the randomiser works on in once instance and keeps that image for all the images

how would i randomize the "$my_img" so that every time it generates an image it creates a new image name

Comment: you can do something with time `md5(microtime())` and use that for image name